# windows 10 install usb stick that runs on Uefi and Bios systems

Tags: windows-10, bootable-media, rufus

I know how to create a usb install stick with Rufus that works on either Uefi/GPT or on Bios/MFT Systems.

But is there any way to create a Stick that supports both flavors at the same time?

Comment: Yes; Use the Media Creation Tool;  What have you tried specifically, this information is required, in order to find the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rufus has a cheat mode (<kbd>Atl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>) to do just that.

For the reason why this is not enabled by default, please see the [Rufus FAQ](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesnt_Rufus_create_a_Windows_installation_USB_that_can_be_booted_in_dual_BIOSUEFI_mode), which also details the cheat mode.